# Why java TreeMap.entrySet returns a set of SimpleImmutableEntry?

Tags: java, immutability, treemap

I have a java application installed on 2 different servers running with java 1.6.0_22-b04 sun and tomcat 6.0.32

The staging server is causing me headaches with the following error :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException : null
   java.util.AbstractMap$SimpleImmutableEntry.setValue (AbstractMap.java:726)
```

Here's the code raising this exception

```
for (Entry<Integer, BigDecimal> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  entry.setValue(new BigDecimal("999"));
}
```

I'm only having this problem on this server. Everything is fine locally and on the other server with the same code.

I found lots of results on google about this exception but they were all linked to hudson.

Comment: Are you sure you want to re-set the values of a Map like that?

Comment: What is the concrete class you are using for the Map?

Comment: @JustinKSU, the title in the question says TreeMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`TreeMap` Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) in Java 6:

> All `Map.Entry` pairs returned by methods in this class and its views represent snapshots of mappings at the time they were produced. They do *not* support the `Entry.setValue` method. (Note however that it is possible to change mappings in the associated map using put.)

So -- why are you even surprised?

Comment: Still doesn't explain why the discrepancy between the two servers and my workstation where the same setValue works perfectly on the same treemap.

Comment: ...No, I suppose it doesn't, but it still indicates that you shouldn't be doing whatever you're doing.

Comment: I replaced the setValue by a put on the map directly

from       
         map.put(entry.getKey(), new BigDeciaml("999"));
to
         entry.setValue(new BigDecimal("999");

Comment: Still wondering why one server was raising this exception while the other one was wonrking perfectly though.

Comment: Finally found that the problem was caused by this JVM option : `-XX:+AggressiveOpts`. It was only present on the server which was raising the exception.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181872/why-java-treemap-entryset-returns-a-set-of-simpleimmutableentry#comment16336232_12182952) server which threw exception had been started with `-XX:+AggressiveOpts` option. 

[JDK-7006877](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7006877) explains why `-XX:+AggressiveOpts` changes `TreeMap` behaviour.

> An experimental implementation of TreeMap was added in 1.6.0_14:
>   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/6u14-137039.html#performance-6u14
>   
> This new implementation is enabled via the command line option -XX:+AggressiveOpts.
>   
> With the standard TreeMap implementation, the value of Map.Entry key/value pairs returned by TreeMap's Iterator can be modified by calling Map.Entry.setValue().
>   
> With the experimental implemention enabled, it is not possible to modify the values in this way. Calls to Map.Entry.setValue() result in an UnsupportedOperationException.

Comment: JDK-7006877 was fixed in 2013 by JDK-8024826 and released in Java 8, so this would only affect Java 7 jre/jdks right?

Comment: Thanks a million. I have been behind this issue for 4 days. This was occurring when atg repository tries to read a data from DB. We were thinking it's a mssql driver issue. Didn't notice that the error was actually throwing from java's library class.

Answer (score 2):

Can you provide a simple example where this fails?

```
TreeMap<Integer, BigDecimal> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put(0, BigDecimal.ZERO);
map.put(1, BigDecimal.ONE);

for (Map.Entry<Integer, BigDecimal> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    entry.setValue(new BigDecimal("999"));
}
System.out.println(map);
```

prints

```
{0=999, 1=999}
```

TreeMap in Java 6 will give an exception for a lone entry

```
map.floorEntry(1).setValue(BigDecimal.TEN); // fails.
```

According to the source, only ConcurrentSkipListMap uses this class.

```
Map<Integer, BigDecimal> map = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();
```

always gives me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.AbstractMap$SimpleImmutableEntry.setValue(AbstractMap.java:759)
```

BTW: I get the same behaviour in Java 6 and 7.

Comment: The exception is raised when setting the value on the map. it is important to know that I do the exact same test case on the other server and everything works as expected.

Comment: Perhaps you have a TreeMap in one case (which doesn't use the SimpleImmutableEntry) and the other uses ConcurrentSkipListMap which does.

Comment: How could the implementations differ? Here's the declaration :
`private final Map<Integer, BigDecimal> map = new TreeMap<Integer, BigDecimal>();`

Comment: TreeMap doesn't use that class for entrySet() so your map is not a TreeMap when it fails or the not is not what you think.

Comment: I have a recent version of Java 6 (update 32) If you are seeing a difference I would first check you really are using the same version of Java on each.  In Java 7 TreeMap doesn't use SimpleImmutableEntry anywhere, but Java 6 update 32 uses it for lone entries.